# How is it correct:$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}n[(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-n\sqrt[n]{n}-1)] = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

It is known that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}[(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-n\sqrt[n]{n}] =1$$
I tried to calculate the limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}n[(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-n\sqrt[n]{n}-1)]. $$
I managed to show that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\frac{n}{\ln{n}}[(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-n\sqrt[n]{n}-1] = 0.$$
Using: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1) = \lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}}{\ln{n}}    (*)$$
and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}-1}{\ln{\sqrt[n]{n}}} =1$$
I found:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}n[(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-n\sqrt[n]{n}-1)] =$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}n[(n+1)(\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-1)-n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)] =$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}n[\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-1}{\ln{\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}}}\cdot\ln{(n+1)}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}-1}{\ln{\sqrt[n]{n}}}\cdot \ln{n}]=$$

$$?=?\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}n[\ln{(n+1)}-\ln{n}]= \lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n= 1$$

Is the result correct?

Is the application of equality (*) correct?

Is there another method of calculating, without derivatives, the respective limit?

Comment: you can always use '\lim' instead of lim .......it makes things nicer

Comment: The opening "known" limit is not correct. $\sqrt[n]n$ and $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ tend to $1$, so $(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-\sqrt[n]n$ tends to $\infty$, not $1$. Are the parentheses in the right places?

Comment: You can't use the starred equality like that because it's not meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the expression $$f(n)=\frac{n^{1/n}-1}{n^{1/n}}$$ which can be rewritten as $$\dfrac{\exp\dfrac{\log n} {n} - 1}{\dfrac{\log n} {n} }=1+\frac{\log n} {2n}+\dots$$ and then $$f(n) \log(n+1)-f(n)\log n=\log(1+1/n)+\frac{(\log(n+1)) ^2}{2(n+1)}-\frac{(\log n) ^2}{2n} +\dots$$ By mean value theorem the second term equals $$\frac{2\log\xi-(\log\xi)^2}{2\xi^2}$$ where $n<\xi<n+1$ and this multiplied by $n$ clearly tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty $.

It follows that $n(f(n+1)\log (n+1)-f(n)\log n) $ has same limit as that of $n\log(1+n^{-1})$ which is $1$.

The above uses derivatives and Taylor expansions and I don't see a clear way to avoid these tools right now.