# Find $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n(\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} - 1)}{\ln{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

So I came across an interesting problem, find: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} [(n+1) \sqrt[n+1]{n+1} - n \sqrt[n]{n}]^\frac{n}{\ln n}$

After proving that $(n+1) \sqrt[n+1]{n+1} - n \sqrt[n]{n}$ converges to $1$, I added $1$ subtracted $1$, and then I needed to find: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{\ln n}[(n+1) \sqrt[n+1]{n+1} - n \sqrt[n]{n} - 1]$

I quickly split this limit into two parts: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\ln n}[n(\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} - \sqrt[n]{n})]$ and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\ln n}(\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} - 1)$. I proved that these two limits are **opposites**, so added
together would equal $0$. There is a problem in this though, if the limits are not finite, their sum would be undefined.

To conclude, I either need to find one of the two limits listed above, or at least prove that one of the limits is finite.

Comment: I see that you are romanian :)))

Comment: might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909506/how-is-it-correct-lim-n-rightarrow-inftynn1-sqrtn1n1-n-sqrtnn?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-1)}{ln(n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{ln(n)}\cdot(\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-1)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{ln(n)}\cdot(e^{\frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}}-1)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{ln(n)}\cdot\frac{(e^{\frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}}-1)}{\frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}}\cdot \frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ln(n+1)}{ln(n)}\cdot \frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{(e^{\frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}}-1)}{\frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}}$$

All of those terms tend to $1$ for the first 2 being obvious and for the last one we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}=0$$ by Cesaro-Stolz so the last term is a fundamental limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$

Comment: I think that you wrote it wrong. It needs to be (n+1)th root, not square root